# CodeCharge Application

Tags: asp.net, codecharge

I need to make small asp.net application in codecharge.
Please tell me how to add server side event into that app and how can i get textbox value in server side.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look through the examples here:

http://examples.codecharge.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound like 'RTFM' but... the Help file that comes with Codecharge is quite extensive and goes through many of the common tasks (in the case of CodeCharge Studio (CCS), it does it for each language - PHP, .NET, perl, JSP, coldfusion, ASP). See the links below for the online version.

An example of using the Server Side events (Before Insert) to modify a control's value is shown in all languages (see '[Replace Control Value Before Inserting](http://docs.codecharge.com/studio50/html/ProgrammingTechniques/HowTo/Other/ReplaceControlValueBeforeInsert.html?toc)' and choose your project's language at top-right of page).

As with most frameworks, a lot of the gathering of POST values from controls are already done and ready to use at run-time. CCS has lists of the properties and methods of its 'components' in the Help as well. Most languages have something like 'GetValue()' in their run-time properties - check the [Text Box Component Reference](http://docs.codecharge.com/studio50/html/Components/Objects/TextBox.html?toc) section of the Help. For .NET it's 'GetFormattedValue()'

CCS also has a lot of pre-built 'Actions' to use in the Events - so in a lot of cases you don't need to code it yourself, there may be an Action to Help. You can also choose an Action, get CCS to make it, double-click on the Action, and view the generated code for tips. You could then delete the Action (don't delete the code, delete the Action and let CCS remove the actual code) and you can then add 'Custom Code' and put in your own. I have used that method when learning a new language in CCS.

Answer (score 0):

You use within an event on the server.
`Login1.GetControl<InMotion.Web.Controls.MTTextBox>("login").Text`